# how to access individual elements of a javascript object literal?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object literal?
I access them in my webpage as
data.list[i].ger or data.list[i].eng

If I want to directly search an entry how can I directly access that entry?
or do I have to do a linear search or a binary search upon sort?

```
data = {
    list: [
        {
            "ger": "A-as",
            "eng": "A as"
        },
        {
            "ger": "A-aws",
            "eng": "a-was "
        },
        {
            "ger": "we",
            "eng": "cv"
        },
        {
            "ger": "q",
            "eng": "w-la-w"
        },....
```

for e.g. if i wanted to access 
"ger": "q","eng": "w-la-w"
I would acces it as data.list[4].ger

is there any way of directly accessing knowing what is the index of that entry?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly search an entry"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#overview). It makes it easy to access data in complex JSON documents, but looks like CSS.

[Check out the examples](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit), it looks pretty much like what you want to do.

For instance, to get the eng version of ger:q, you would do `.ger:val("q") ~ .eng`

You can [download it here](http://jsonselect.org/js/jsonselect.js) and use it with `JSONSelect.match` or `JSONSelect.forEach`.

Comment: I looked at the website..But how do I use it? .ger:val("q") ~ .eng is exactly what I want, but how do I use it in my JavaScript?

Comment: Updated my answer with a download link.

Comment: thanks...JSONSelect.match(".ger:val("we") ~ .eng",data); gives me  an error in firefox - missing a ) in argument list

Comment: @user Is the issue that you need to replace the double quotes around "we" with single quotes as 'we'? I think the JS parser is seeing that as ".ger:val(", then some variable named `we`, then ") ~ .eng". You probably want `".ger:val('we') ~ .eng"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to search through your array, I'd go with something like

```
function lookupTrans(value, fromLang, toLang) {
  for (var i = 0, dataLen = data.list.length; i < dataLen; i++) {
    if (data.list[i][fromLang] === value) {
      return data.list[i][toLang];
      // return i (if you're lookup for just the index number)
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

However, I do want to make sure you're not trying to just do one-way internationalization. If that's the case, I'd recommend just using named keys:

```
var i18n = {
  "translation": {
    "en": "translation",
    "ja": "hon'yaku"
  },
  "list": {
    "en": "list",
    "ja": "risuto"
  },
  "example": {
    "en": "example",
    "ja": "rei"
  },
  "imbueWithConfidence": {
    "en": "Let's translate!",
    "ja": "Hon'yaku shimashou!"
  }
};
```