# Using Object keys to compare against data set and insert object values

Tags: google-apps-script

*Thank you in advance!*

**Goal/Help Request:**

I'd like to use the array I have in my code (which I think is an object literal?) and if a **exact match** occurs from the data set (Food column), it inserts the paired answer from the array into the "Pairing" column.

**Issue/Thoughts:**

I think I need to use Object.values()& Object.keys(). I'm having a difficult time trying to get my function to run through the data and compare....I thought a for statement would work but it doesn't seem so and my forEach code says it's not a function and I'm a bit lost on how to have it go through each corresponding row like you would do with i++.

**Sheet before script:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Data:**

| Food | Pairing | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple toast |  |  |
| apple cheese |  |  |
| orange |  |  |
| orange peel |  |  |
| apple apple apple |  |  |
| orange orange |  |  |
| orange toast |  |  |

**CODE:**

```
    function apples() {
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
          const combo = {
                          'apple toast':'juice',
                          'apple cheese':'water',
                          'orange':'milk',
                          'orange peel':'OJ'
                          }
    const food = sheet.getRange("A2:A5").getValues().flat();
    const foodrownum = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    const pairing = sheet.getRange("B2:B5");

    var keys = Object.keys(combo)

    combo.forEach(function(item,index,array){
          if(item===food){
              sheet.getRange(2,2,foodrownum).setValue(Object.values(combo));
          }
    });

    }//end of function
```

**References:**

1. [how to access individual elements of a javascript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243736/how-to-access-individual-elements-of-a-javascript-object-literal)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#object_literals
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values
5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: I'd populate my object with properties equal to column headers and and array with values the each line of the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When `setValue` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- `combo` is JSON object. In this case, you cannot directly use `forEach`.
- In the case of `sheet.getRange(2,2,foodrownum).setValue(Object.values(combo))`, when your value of `combo` is used, only `juice` is put to the column "B".
- I thought that in your situation, the method for creating the output values from the values of column "A" using JSON object of `combo` might be suitable.

When these points are reflected to a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function apples() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const combo = {
    'apple toast': 'juice',
    'apple cheese': 'water',
    'orange': 'milk',
    'orange peel': 'OJ'
  };
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [combo[a.trim()] || null]);
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, using `combo` and the values of the column "A", the new values are put to the column "B".

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and I appreciate the additional references I can look into for clarification.  I'll have to do some research on JSON object since I didn't know that was it, appreciate it!

Comment: To better understand does `.map(([a])` pull the values of the range and then compare it against the first elements of the JSON array using `[combo[a`?

Comment: @User1938985 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your additional question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand your additional question.

Comment: No need to apologize, my question was on this line of code `const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [combo[a.trim()] || null]);` . I was wondering if `.map(([a]` pulls the values of the range in `A2:A` and compares it to the `JSON Object` with `[combo[a`

Comment: @User1938985 Thank you for replying. If my understanding of your additional question is correct, for example, when `a` of `combo[a.trim()]` is `apple toast`, `combo[a.trim()]` returns `"juice"`. When `a` of `combo[a.trim()]` is `sample`, `combo[a.trim()]` returns `undefined`. In this case, `null` is returned by `combo[a.trim()] || null`. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can try this:

```
function apples() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const combo = {
    'apple toast': 'juice',
    'apple cheese': 'water',
    'orange': 'milk',
    'orange peel': 'OJ'
  }
  const food = sheet.getRange("A2:A8").getValues().flat();
  const pairing = sheet.getRange("B2:B8");

  const entries = Object.entries(combo);

  for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
    if (food[i] in combo) {
      pairing.getCell(i + 1, 1).setValue(combo[food[i]]) //Adds the value to each row depending on the key value
    }
    else {
      pairing.getCell(i + 1, 1).setValue('Not found') 
/*This since both combo and your sheet elements are not the same size
and getCell specifies where we want to insert the value of the key found*/
    }
  }
}
```

As to why you are getting the error, basically the way it was implemented was not correct as [per documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function#function_called_on_the_wrong_object)

- [getCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column)

Comment: nice thank you this was easy to follow and I appreciate the comments on the code! To clarify for me `combo[food[i]])`  , how does that pull the matching element from the array?  I think I understand  the if statement prior.

Comment: take setValue out of the loop, resource intensive.